# Trying to debug this source code {c#}

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Below is a portion of my source code and I am trying to debug it and can't figure out what to do.  I have run the debugger that I use on visual studio and when it pops up it says "does not exists in the current context" at gameB and when I look at the possible fixes, I choose to make an existence in the Main Window and then it underlines the rest of that line except the arguments. And this happens anywhere there is a gameB.

Source code:

```
public void startGame()
{

    // Clean up the display
    gameB.resetGameBoard(lettersUsed);

    // Reset the game state values
    turnNumber = 1;
    lettersUsed = 0;
    displayPlayerTurn(1);

    playerOneScore = 0;
    playerTwoScore = 0;
    lblP1_Score.Content = "0";
    lblP2_Score.Content = "0";


    // Show player one's turn
    gameB.setupPlayerLetters(1, ref lettersUsed);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Where is `gameB` declared?

Comment: I think you need to create an object of type GameB. GameB Name = new GameB(). Without that object being instantiated in scope you can't really access it.

Comment: @Chris1804505 It doesn't necessarily need to be.

Comment: @Ron: Edited my original comment. Which was about making sure that GameB was public. True GameB doesn't necessarily have to be declared as public but it is an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

Error is pretty self explanatory as it says that you need to create a variable of type `gameB` since it doesn't exist in your `startGame()` function scope.

> "gameB does not exists in the current context"

To debug, right click on a code line and select `Add Breakpoint`. Run your application and start debugging.